# How can I use sed line by line?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, sed

I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line
    do
        new=$(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" $line)
        sed "s|$line: .*|: $new|" file.yml
    done < <(awk 'NR>1{sub(/:.*/,"");print $1}' file.yml)
```

The `file.yml` content:

```
catalog/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/garamondcondot-book/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham-narrow/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/greatvibes/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/indie-flower/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/katibeh/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/lobster-two/fonts.css: 1484139539
```

So, what I want to do?

I have `file.yml` with some file source and UNIX timestamp (last modofied date). I want to check every file with `git log`. From `git log` I receive the new timestamp modified date and I need to replace the old date with the new one.

What I expected:

```
catalog/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1484135987
catalog/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1484136578
```

What I get (and thus why I think `sed` doesn't work line by line):

```
: 1549375252
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/overlay.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/customselect/css/styles.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/jquery/christmasTime/christmasTime.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/garamondcondot-book/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham-narrow/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/greatvibes/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/indie-flower/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/katibeh/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/lobster-two/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/museo/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/myriad-pro/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/notera/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/sr-cart-icons/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/ageprotector.css: 1484139539
: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/customselect/css/styles.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/jquery/christmasTime/christmasTime.css: 1484139539

catalog/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/garamondcondot-book/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham-narrow/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/greatvibes/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/indie-flower/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/katibeh/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/lobster-two/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/museo/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/myriad-pro/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/notera/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/sr-cart-icons/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/ageprotector.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/overlay.css: 1484139539
: 1484139539

catalog/view/javascript/jquery/christmasTime/christmasTime.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/garamondcondot-book/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham-narrow/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/gotham/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/greatvibes/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/indie-flower/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/katibeh/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/lobster-two/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/museo/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/myriad-pro/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/notera/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/fonts/sr-cart-icons/fonts.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/ageprotector.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/overlay.css: 1484139539
catalog/view/javascript/customselect/css/styles.css: 1484139539
: 1484139539

catalog/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/garamondcondot-book/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/gotham-narrow/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/gotham/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/greatvibes/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/indie-flower/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/katibeh/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/lobster-two/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/museo/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/myriad-pro/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/notera/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/fonts/sr-cart-icons/fonts.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/ageprotector.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/javascript/auroraoverlay/overlay.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/javascript/customselect/css/styles.css: 1590479145
catalog/view/javascript/jquery/christmasTime/christmasTime.css: 1590479145
```

Comment: `"s|$line: .*|: $new|"` You are outputting the file content and substituting the whole line.

Comment: Okay, any suggestion?

Comment: couple suggestions: 1) reduce the examples to just a couple files (way too much stuff in that huge block of output) and 2) consider building a new file of timestamps and when done just overwrite the original (or archive the original and rename the new file to `file.yml`); as for pulling the filenames from `file.yml` ... `awk -F":"{print $1}'` or `cut -d":" -f1` are easier to read/understand

Comment: Okay, thank you. The main problem is sed change the timestamp in every file like in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> sed "s|$line: .*|: $new|" file.yml
> ```

`sed` outputs the content of the file, it doesn't modify the file.

`$line: .*` would match *the whole line*, so it will remove it and replace *the whole line* with `: $new`.

If you have GNU sed you can use `-i` sed argument to modify the file in place:

```
sed -i "s|$line: .*|$line: $new|" file.yml
```

or better:

```
sed -i "s|\($line: \).*|\1$new|" file.yml
```

But you can't read and write to the same file at the same time!

Also `sub(/:.*/,"")` seems strange - just read with `:` as separator, that's what IFS is for. `while IFS=: read -r line ignore_the_rest; do ... done <file.yml`.

Instead of replacing the file in place on each file line by line, just output a new file content and put it in the destination.

```
{
   IFS= read -r preserve_first_line
   printf "%s\n" "$preserve_first_line"
   while IFS=':' read -r line _; do
       new=$(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" "$line")
       echo "$line: $new"
   done
} < file.yml > new_file.yml
mv new_file.yml file.yml
```

If you really want to do inplace editing, first cache the files so that you do not read and write at the same time to the same file.

```
readarray -t files < <(awk 'NR>1{sub(/:.*/,"");print $1}' file.yml)
for line in "${files[@]}"; do
    new=$(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" "$line")
    sed -i "s|\($line: \).*|\1$new|" file.yml
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed by itself working line by line, no need to run it in loop, just do this

```
sed 's/\(^.*\): \(.*\)/echo \1: $(code_to_get_new_timestamp)/e' file.yml
```